# Sculpting with inflate not working as expected

Tags: sculpting

I'm following the donut tutorial using version 2.83, and have an issue with the inflate tool which doesn't seem to work like I expect from the way Andrew uses it. Take a look at around the [10 minute mark on youtube](https://youtu.be/6OTX3ZdYvEA?t=599).

When I use it on my droplets, they get more "lifted" than inflated. See recording below.

Things I tried:

- varying the strength
- varying the radius
- other brush settings

What am I doing wrong here?

[image: Recording of my issue]

Comment: Did you apply your solidify modifier?

Comment: Oh jeezzz...You are right, thanks! I reverted to a previous save which didn't have them applied. If you create an answer I will mark it approved.